# The optimization of the following queries

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have database table IPv4:

```
id          int(11) PK
ip          bigint(10)
mask        bigint(10)
broadcast   bigint(10)
```

I'm trying to make a text search of ip address, like user input 83.1.1.1/24 and I search for it using the following query:

```
SELECT `ip`, `broadcast` 
FROM `IPv4` 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(INET_NTOA(`ip`), "/", BIT_COUNT(`mask`)) LIKE '%:searchStr%'
```

Then I want to get the path to the found IP address (hierarchical tree):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `IPv4` WHERE (ip <= :ip) AND (broadcast > :broadcast)
```

Is it possible to make all of it in one query?

**EDIT**

Moved forward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
FROM (
        SELECT ip, broadcast
        FROM IPv4
        WHERE CONCAT( INET_NTOA(  `ip` ) ,  "/", BIT_COUNT(  `mask` ) ) LIKE  '%:searchStr%'
    ) AS t1

INNER JOIN IPv4 t2
WHERE t2.ip <= t1.ip AND t2.broadcast >= t1.broadcast 
ORDER BY t2.mask
```

This does the job, maybe possible even better?

Answer (score 2):

When you have stored your ips and masks with `inet_` you can use the & operator to compare them?

```
ip = inet_ntoa( '192.168.100.12' )
mask = inet_ntoa( '255.255.255.0' )

ip & mask == inet_ntoa( '192.168.100.1' ) & inet_ntoa( '255.255.255.0' )
```

should return true when matches.

http://databaseblog.myname.nl/2011/07/working-with-ips-in-mysql-and-mariadb.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't need this, I'm trying to create a text search, it should be able to search if user enter full address or just a part, for example: 2.31/24

Comment: @nn4n4s: as far as i understood you are searching an ip with netmask inside a table with ips and netmasks. maybe it is faster to transform the filled in ips and netmask strings and then search in an database. anyway. what ever is good for you :)